# Difficulty setting up a private BIND DNS server for an office network

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm setting up an internal website for a small company. I also set up a private DNS server inside the office network that resolves the hostname of said internal website. I then changed the router's DHCP settings, setting a public DNS server as the primary DNS, and setting my private DNS server as the secondary. However, I did something wrong and it's causing network instability inside the company. Here's what I did:

1. The company network's gateway adderss/router's address is 192.168.0.1.
2. I set up an internal website on a server with a fixed IP address
   of 192.168.0.10.
3. On the same server, I set up a BIND DNS server. I want it to resolve the hostname "mywebsite.local" to 192.168.0.10, and forward all other queries to the public DNS servers. The BIND server's configuration file looks like the following

```
zone "." {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders{
        192.168.0.1;
    };
};

zone "local" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/local.hosts";
        };

zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

4. `/var/lib/bind/local.hosts` looks like the following

```
local.  IN      SOA     ns.local. foo.bar.com. (
                        1602646014
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
local.  IN      NS      ns.local.
ns.local.       IN      A       192.168.0.10
mywebsite.local.      IN      A       192.168.0.10
```

5. I changed the DHCP settings on the router, giving 8.8.8.8 as primary DNS server, and giving 192.168.0.10 as secondary DNS server.
6. After the above settings are done, my clients experienced network outrage.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed the DHCP settings on the router, giving 8.8.8.8 as primary DNS server, and giving 192.168.0.10 as secondary DNS server.

This is not correct. If you specify multiple DNS servers, they are all expected to provide the same content – if Google's 8.8.8.8 responds that "mywebsite.local" is unknown, the client will take that as the final answer and will not try the other server.

Clients will only switch to another server if the original server does not respond *at all*.

So you should list only your custom server – and if you want reliability in case it goes down, then you should set up two local servers (one of them replicating the local zones from another).

> After the above settings are done, my clients experienced network outrage.

For network *outage*, make sure the global options section in named.conf specifies your entire LAN subnet under `allow-recursion`.

```
allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; ::1; 192.168.0.0/24; }
```

To avoid *outrage* you should test configuration before imposing it on everyone else – that is, manually verify that your server answers DNS queries the way you want. Use the `nslookup` tool from another Windows PC, or `dig` / `host` from a Linux or macOS computer – they let you query a specified server without having to change DHCP settings:

```
nslookup mywebsite.local 192.168.0.10
nslookup google.com 192.168.0.10
host google.com 192.168.0.10
```

The second possible problem is that by changing your DHCP settings you might also have told the router *itself* to use your DNS server, thus creating a loop: your named forwards a query to the router, which then forwards it to your server, which then forwards it to the router, which then forwards it to your server...

To avoid this, specify e.g. 8.8.8.8 as the forward destination in your named.conf, instead of specifying the router's address.

(Not all routers link both settings that way, but some do.)

#### Other notes

I would recommend against using `.local` for DNS, since it could conflict with mDNS. Consider something like `.lan` instead. (But IMO, a better choice for a company network would be to use a subdomain of the company's Internet domain, e.g. `.lan.example.org` or `.corp.example.com`.)

I would also suggest defining the zone class in named.conf (`zone "local." IN {...}`) and the common suffix using the $ORIGIN macro in the zonefile, so that you wouldn't have to repeat them for every record:

```
$ORIGIN local.
$TTL 1h

@               SOA     ns admin.mycompany.com. ( 1602646014 3h 1h 7d 1h )
                NS      ns

ns              A       192.168.0.10
mywebsite       A       192.168.0.10
```